# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cases, value = list(monthly = c(2026.08333333333, : replacement has 56 rows, data has 554

Tags: r, dplyr

The code that I am using:

```
cases_df$monthly <- as.yearmon(cases_df$positive_date)
cases_df$cases <- NA 
cases_df$cases <- cases_df %>% count(monthly)
```

I am trying to get my count monthly in r, and replace in the column that I have created which is call cases, however, the data cant be really replaced since it has 554 rows.

[image]

Comment: `count()` returns a summarized data frame, you can't store that as a variable.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg